# java.lang.ClassCastException while trying to print container id in jade

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have a code  for finding the list of containers from the ams in jade using queryPlatformAction method. I am getting a problem for typecasting the container id while putting the sop statement at the end..

```
     Result result = (Result) content;
     List listOfPlatforms = (List) result.getValue();
     Iterator iter = listOfPlatforms.iterator();
     while (iter.hasNext()) 
       {
       ContainerID next = (ContainerID) iter.next();
       System.out.println(next.getID());
       }
```

It is throwing an exception to me.

The exception is: java.lang.ClassCastException: jade.util.leap.ArrayList cannot
be cast to java.util.List
please help.

Comment: which line is giving the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The two types of `List` are not in the same class hierarchy and therefore cannot be cast between each other, hence a `ClassCastException`.

The [jade.util.leap.List](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/util/leap/List.html) interface is used within JADE to provide a `List` collection that looks the same between the different back-ends of JADE, but which is actually implemented differently. From the Javadocs, [ArrayList](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/util/leap/ArrayList.html) only extends `Object`.

To fix this, declare `listOfPlatforms` to be of type `jade.util.leap.List`.